# jquery and angular 6 change detection and data binding

Tags: jquery, angular

I am using Angular 6 along with Jquery for my web application. I have a button from jquery. On click of that button, I want to trigger a function from my angular 6. But I have not found any functions or any source regarding this. So, Is there anyone who can help me in doing this issue. I have tried out many of possible steps but I cannot get the best solution for this issue. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: can you share the code , that maybe help to slove your problem

Comment: Why you want to use JQuery with angular is the first question.

Comment: I want to implement Jwplayer on my application. For that, I have to use jquery for integrating player(Hls player). So,I have to implement Jquery.

Comment: @Robert I have updated my post with code If you want I can provide exact code on jsfiddle.

Comment: @SubashTimalsina please do

Comment: @SubashTimalsina, It is highly not recommended to use JQuery inside Angular Project..

Comment: @ManirajfromKarur but is there any solution for Live Tv player on angular so that I cannot use jquery for implementing it. please help me